# About auto rounding result in java from double to integer?

Tags: java, integer, double, rounding

The output of below code in Java is `3.0`.

Why isn't it `3.3333333...`?

```
double a = 10 / 3;
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `int / int` returns an `int` (regardless of what you assign it to afterwards).

So `10 / 3` returns `3` (integer division rounds down).

This would only then get converted to `double`.

To fix this, make one of the values a `double` (so it's `double / int`, which returns a `double`):

```
double a = 10.0 / 3;
```

or

```
double a = (double)10 / 3;
```